# Put on the bottom elements in an App on Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

I have an issue with my App on Android Studio.
I want to know how can I put on the bottom of my layout (in a fixed position) without ruining the structure on various smartphones. I'm using a Linear Layout and the elements to put at the bottom are :
Edit-text (comments area) + Button "Send comment" in the right of the Edit-Text. Thank you.

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NaiSVz3D <-- Here is my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal approach is to use a ConstraintLayout, because it will give you a lot of options to do that. Using a LinearLayout if the linear layout height is match parent. You can set the item property of `gravity=bottom`.

Sample Code of constraint layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_input"
        android:hint="Taper votre message"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZfcsDYQ (Tested with my phone)
https://ibb.co/w4v01sK (Tested with AVD on Android Studio). I used constraints but I don't know what the problem is..

Comment: @Davencode can you please share the xml for the layout? It will help to understand the problem. You can edit your question and add code.

Comment: @Davencode - I checked your layout the one without constraintLayout, it is a very complicated, nested and over-engineered layout - 4 levels of LinearLayoutCompat inside a LinearLayout. They have 2 recyclerViews and other views. You should check the Android guidelines and use fragments for sections and include layouts, etc. Also, I checked the images you provided. what is the issue in the layout? The editText and Button are aligned to the bottom of the page. Can you explain the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I want to put on a fixed bottom position the 2 elements (edit-text and button) but when I see that on my phone I saw the two elements more up like this https://ibb.co/ZfcsDYQ . And when I see the https://ibb.co/w4v01sK on my AVD manager, There's no moving up and I wanted that positioning. My question is.. why this thing happen? It's about the size screen? ho can I fix this?

Comment: Share the layout code, we can try to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a new Layout called **ConstraintLayout**. You have to put this new layout at the same level as your linear layout and it will not destroy your work.